# Android BLE send data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

The question is simple, is it possible to send data over Bluetooth low energy 4.0 ?
I've searched an tried several programms, but my product is on Bluetooth 4.0 and said that is not compatible with it. Did I need to go with normal bluetooth with a conncetion pair ?

Thanks !

Comment: Of course you can send data with BLE. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Yes, I don't find the method to send data, advertising is not possible on BLE 4.0, do you have any example to send data in BLE 4.0 ?

Comment: I don't know where you have got your information from, but it seems like a bad and inaccurate source. Advertising is of course possible on BLE 4.0. Without advertising you wouldn't be able to establish a connection or advertise data. Do you want to broadcast data by advertising or do you want to establish a connection and send data over that? If you want to be connected, there are thousands of examples online, just search...

Comment: it's just the result of multiple of example in android studio projects. Everytime, I wanted to advertise data, the result was "advertising is not compatible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some old Android devices don't support Advertising, but it's not because Bluetooth 4.0 does not support advertising.

That's either because the manufacturer that configured the software disabled Advertising initiated by apps, or it's disabled since the Bluetooth chip does not support advertising and being connected concurrently (which was a limitation in Bluetooth 4.0). Also Android pre-lollipop didn't have an advertising API at all.

In the second case, advertising is probably disabled since connecting to devices "should always work". If an app starts advertising, we of course don't want connection attempts to fail. This restriction was lifted in Bluetooth 4.1.

When you use an Android smartphone and connect to some kind of embedded device, you usually want to use the phone as scanner/initiator and the embedded device as a peripheral (advertising). Then you don't need to advertise on the Android side and therefore are not affected by this issue.